# Dynamically Query in a Report?

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

I'm trying to build some reports.
I Have this query:

```
SELECT  Agente.UserUri as Agente, COUNT(Agente.UserUri) as NumeroRisposte

FROM    Users as User1, Users as User2, Users as StartedByUser, Users as Agente,
        Phones as FromPhone, Phones as ConnectedPhone,
        SessionDetails as IVRSession, SessionDetails as AgenteSession,
        VoipDetails,
        ClientVersions as Client1Version, ClientVersions as Client2Version

WHERE   VoipDetails.SessionIdTime = IVRSession.SessionIdTime AND     
        VoipDetails.SessionIdSeq = IVRSession.SessionIdSeq AND
        VoipDetails.FromNumberId = FromPhone.PhoneId AND
        VoipDetails.FromNumberId = ConnectedPhone.PhoneId AND

        IVRSession.SessionIdTime = AgenteSession.ReplacesDialogIdTime AND    
        IVRSession.SessionIdSeq = AgenteSession.ReplacesDialogIdSeq AND
        Agente.UserId = AgenteSession.User1Id AND

        User1.UserId = IVRSession.User1Id AND
        User2.UserId = IVRSession.User2Id AND
        StartedByUser.UserId = IVRSession.SessionStartedById AND

        Client1Version.VersionId = IVRSession.User1ClientVerId AND
        Client2Version.VersionId = IVRSession.User2ClientVerId AND
        (Client1Version.ClientType = 1024 or Client2Version.ClientType = 1024) AND

        User2.UserUri = 'ivr0679071new' AND
        IVRSession.InviteTime BETWEEN '18/02/2014 16:28:19' AND '19/02/2014 16:28:19'

        GROUP BY Agente.UserUri
        ORDER BY Agente.UserUri
```

Don't try to understand the query.

I just want to know how to use Reports Parameters to filtering the query by using them in the BETWEEN condition.

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the two date strings (e.g. '18/02/2014 16:28:19') in your SQL with parameter placeholders e.g. @StartDate AND @EndDate.

Then I would add two Report Parameters StartDate and EndDate.  Data Type would be Date.

Answer (score 0):

change this code from this

```
BETWEEN '18/02/2014 16:28:19' AND '19/02/2014 16:28:19'
```

to this

```
BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

this will automatically add 2 Report paramaters.